# Trying to extend my result to have 8 digits after a decimal

Tags: c++, decimal, scientific-computing

I'm trying to extend the result on my program to 8 digits after the decimal point. I went over this page (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios_base/precision/) but I'm not having any luck changing the result. Any suggestions? Thanks you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

long double taylorSeriesToCalculateCosine(long double x, int degree);
long factorial( int input );

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    cout << "Cosine of .3: ";
    cout << taylorSeriesToCalculateCosine(.3,3) << endl;

    return 0;
}

// taylor series to calculate cosine
long double taylorSeriesToCalculateCosine(long double x,int degree){

    int i = 0;
    long double accumulation = 0;
    int cosInputArray[4] = {1,0,-1,0};

    while (i < degree) {

        int input = cosInputArray[i%4];

        accumulation += input*((pow(x, i))/factorial(i)); 
        i++;
    }

    return accumulation;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
Cosine of .3: 0.955
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need [`std::setprecision`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision) from the `<iomanip>` header:

```
cout << setprecision( 8 ) << taylorSeriesToCalculateCosine(.3,3) << endl;
```

If you want the result to *always* have a certain width, use

```
cout << setfill('0') << left << setw(10) << setprecision(8)
     << taylorSeriesToCalculateCosine(.3,3) << endl;
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work [here](http://liveworkspace.org/code/4cvdpz$20). Maybe something else is needed as well?

Comment: The result seems to be almost exactly `0.955`. OP: Do you expect added zeroes to *always* have 8 digits, e.g. `0.95500000`?

Comment: Hmmm I thinking if you change the degree to a higher number than three the result should be different though. I'm not sure though.

Comment: I was leaving out the std::. I didn't think it was needed because I was using namespace std. Thanks all! it worked.

Answer (score 2):

As the article in the link states:

```
cout << "Cosine of .3: ";
std::cout.precision(10);
cout << taylorSeriesToCalculateCosine(.3,3) << endl;
```

that's about it.